# Passing variable names to the count() function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the count() function to return the levels of a column in R. I have 37 columns and I wanted to know if there is a way to pass column names other than typing them out.

I am currently using,

```
> x1Count <- totalCount%>% group_by(Country) %>count(X1.Environmental.Regulation)%>% drop_na()
```

I want to run this through a loop with the count() function taking the column names from a list like colnames(totalCount).

Is there another way to pass inputs to the count() function that will allow me to use column numbers or refer another list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change the string into a symbol (with `sym`) and evaluate (`!!!`).  In the below example, we get the frequency count of the columns 4 and 5, grouped by 'Country'

```
library(tidyverse)
totalCount %>%
       group_by(Country) %>%
       count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[4:5]))
```

Comment: @A.Suliman  It is the issue with multiple columns, `syms` instead of `sym`

Comment: Thank you! This works. I can now simply put this through a loop to get individual factor counts.

Comment: @datan00b You can use `map` i.e. `map(names(iris)[1:3], ~ iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% count(!! rlang::sym(.x)))`

Comment: Also, is it possible to use the rlang:: syntax to pass the variable name to <fill> in ggplot?

Comment: @datan00b  Yes, you can check.  I think the dev version already have that feature